# How to get the modern logic formulas in Principia Mathematica

Tags: lo.logic

Recently, we have contrived some procedures based on resolution method. So, we want to test these procedures.

I know that many propositions are presented by logic formulas in Principia Mathematica. But I do not know how to get all the modern logical formulas in Principia Mathematica. Has anyone done similar work (i.e., converted or translated these original formulas to modern ones)?

Would you like to give me some guidance? Many thanks.

Comment: Or futher, Who has converted these orginal formulas to conjunctive normal forms, even in Propositional logic? I want to use it as an benchmark.

Comment: Bernard Linsky writes in his article on the notation of Principia that rewriting it in modern notation would "drastically alter the very content of the book". Perhaps this is why those who are familiar with the book have not published translations into modern notation. http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/

Comment: This might be useful: http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/pm54.43.html